# How to get secure baseurl (https) in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, url, base-url, object-manager

with this code im getting http://url.com
i want to get https://url.com
using object manager. i'm using magento 2.0.4

```
 echo $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB); echo '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
 $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,true);
```

Plese Note yoo need to add secure url in **Store-> Configuration -> Web -> Base URLs (Secure)**

Please check screenshot
[image]

Comment: no didn't get from it,  in Store-> Configuration -> Web -> Base URLs (Secure) i added:  https://url.com in this field  'Secure Base URL'  , next field 'Secure Base Link URL' i added:   {{secure_base_url}} is this ok?

Comment: in Secure Base URL  you need to define like (https://url.com)

Answer (score 0):

I am daam sure below code will work

```
$store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB,true);
```

Why?? just check  declaration  in below class

```
/vendor/magento/framework/Url/ScopeInterface.php
```

and check 2nd param

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager            
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

echo $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK, true);
```

You can check more about the function `getBaseUrl` in `Magento\Store\Model\Store` Store Model class.

Answer (score 0):

For reference :vendor/magento/module-store/Test/Unit/Model/Service/StoreConfigManagerTest.php

```
/**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\Service\StoreConfigManager
         */
        protected $model;


    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $storeCollectionFactoryMock;

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|\Magento\Store\Model\Data\StoreConfigFactory
     */
    protected $storeConfigFactoryMock;

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfigMock;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->storeConfigFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Store\Model\Data\StoreConfigFactory::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['create'])
            ->getMock();
        $this->storeCollectionFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(
            \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory::class
        )->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(['create'])
            ->getMock();
        $this->scopeConfigMock = $this->createMock(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class);

        $this->model = new \Magento\Store\Model\Service\StoreConfigManager(
            $this->storeCollectionFactoryMock,
            $this->scopeConfigMock,
            $this->storeConfigFactoryMock
        );
    }
```

AND GET BY THIS:

```
$code = 'default';
    $result = $this->model->getStoreConfigs([$code]);
    $result[0]->getSecureBaseUrl();
```